# How is app using cellular data after selectively turned off?

Tags: iphone, applications, cellular-data

One of the apps set to Disallow use of cellular data (Solitaire) uses the most cellular data of any app. This is despite the switch Always being set to Disallow use of cellular data.

Is there another way to block a specific app from using cellular data?
I don’t want to turn off cellular data altogether because my low budget provider doesn’t hold mms for redelivery(!).

I have turned it on (moved switch to Allow use of cellular data), restarted phone, turned it off (moved switch to Disallow use), and restarted phone again. And restarted many times since. It still uses cellular data.

[extra clarification notes]
iPhone 7,  ios 14.4.2,  WiFi Assist is always disabled.
On the Cellular page of Settings under the section heading Cellular Data is the list of apps that have attempted use of cellular data. For the user to allow or disallow use of cellular data on a per-app basis is a switch next to each app. I have set many apps to Disallow use of  cellular data, including Solitaire, which continues to use cellular data anyway.

It’s not alone, others like Backgammon and Paper.io also used cellular data despite being switched off. But Solitaire uses the most data, hence the focus on Solitaire.

[image: switch off but still top data user]

Comment: I know it's not an answer but the app sounds scammy. I would be tempted to just delete it and find another solitaire app.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question about whether there is another way to prevent cellular data usage on a per-app basis: **no**.

If you disallow cellular data to be used by a particular app, then it cannot (or rather, I should say *should* not, in case there actually is a bug in iOS) access your cellular data. It's important to note that the number you see below the app (256 MB in your case) shows the **total amount** of cellular data consumed by the app **to date**, since the last time you reset your cellular data statistics. It seems as if you previously allowed Solitaire to use cellular data (and it has cumulatively consumed 256 MB of data), and only recently you have turned it off. Perhaps you are merely misinterpreting the number underneath the app?

Now that you have turned off cellular data usage for Solitaire, do you notice the data consumption *increase*? If that's the case, then iOS has a serious bug. If not, then everything is working as it should be.

Comment: Scroll down to the bottom of the list and reset the current period if you haven't already.

Comment: To add new information - same issue confirmed on ios 17.2 with the Photos app. Cell data for photos was turned off the first day i got my new 15 pro, but continues to happen. further, this issue has only started since getting the new 15 pro a couple weeks ago - never had a problem with it before on last phone (13 pro) or any other prior/previous models.